# What is the difference between hook_preprocess_page and hook_preprocess_html?

Tags: 7, theming

I see that both `hook_preprocess_page()` and `hook_preprocess_html()` are implementations of `hook_preprocess_HOOK()`, but I don't understand when to use which.

`hook_preprocess_page` is called first, but that doesn't really help me understand who is calling it.

Looking at the `debug_print_backtrace()` output, it's getting called by `theme()`, but that doesn't really get me to the answer.

Is it simply defined by the array that is passed into `drupal_render()`?

Comment: It's in the log message, but I edited the function names to align them with the API docs.

Comment: `template_preprocess_page()` is different from `hook_preprocess_page()`, and there is documentation for [hook_preprocess_HOOK](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7), in the same way there is for [hook_process_HOOK](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21theme.api.php/function/hook_process_HOOK/7).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`hook_preprocess_page` is the preprocess hook invoked when the [page.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/7) template file is used, and `hook_preprocess_html` is the preprocess hook invoked when the [html.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!html.tpl.php/7) template file is used.

Both the preprocess hooks are invoked when a page is rendered with `theme('page')`, since the page element defined from [system_element_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_element_info/7) defines html as theme wrapper.

```
  $types['page'] = array(
    '#show_messages' => TRUE,
    '#theme' => 'page',
    '#theme_wrappers' => array('html'),
  );
```

[system_theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_theme/7) then defines html as follows.

```
'html' => array(
  'render element' => 'page',
  'template' => 'html',
),
```

As for when to implement `hook_preprocess_html()`, you implement it to alter the variables used in the html.tpl.php file, which by default has the following content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php print $language->language; ?>" version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0" dir="<?php print $language->dir; ?>"<?php print $rdf_namespaces; ?>>

<head profile="<?php print $grddl_profile; ?>">
  <?php print $head; ?>
  <title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>
  <?php print $styles; ?>
  <?php print $scripts; ?>
</head>
<body class="<?php print $classes; ?>" <?php print $attributes;?>>
  <div id="skip-link">
    <a href="#main-content" class="element-invisible element-focusable"><?php print t('Skip to main content'); ?></a>
  </div>
  <?php print $page_top; ?>
  <?php print $page; ?>
  <?php print $page_bottom; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, it contains just the HTML tags that wrap a page content, available in `$page`. With that, you can change the content of the `<head>` tag, the page title (the one that goes in the `<title>` tag in the `<head>` tag), the CSS styles and the JavaScript files added to a page, the classes and the attributes for the `<body>` tag.
With the page.tpl.php template file, you can change more of the page being rendered, including the site name, the site slogan, the page title, and the feeds associated with the page. For most of them, there is a specific Drupal function/hook you should instead use.

`hook_preprocess_HOOK` is the generic hook name used for all the preprocess hooks, in the same way `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` is the hook name used for a class of alteration hooks.

Answer (score 8):

`hook_preprocess_page` and `hook_preprocess_html` are theme layer hooks you can use to add variables that can be used in your templates (`page.tpl.php` & `html.tpl.php`).

`hook_preprocess_hook` is the big theme layer hook that page and html use, and the custom ones you've made in `hook_theme()` as well.

For example, here is the declaration of `hook_theme()`:

```
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'custom_theme_function' => array(
      'variables' => NULL
      'template' => 'custom-theme-template', // available as custom-theme-template.tpl.php
    ),
  );
}
```

and here are your preprocess functions:

```
mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
    $vars['variable'] = 'string'; // $variable will be available in page.tpl.php
}

mytheme_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
    $vars['variable'] = 'string'; // $variable will be available in html.tpl.php
}

mytheme_preprocess_custom_theme_function(&$vars) {
    $vars['variable'] = 'string';  // $variable will be available in the template you specified in mymodule_theme() (custom-theme-template.tpl.php)
}
```

additionally `hook_preprocess()` allows you to capture multiple theme hooks, and add variables in it as well

```
mymodule_preprocess(&$vars, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'custom_theme_function') {
    $vars['variable'] = 'string'; // $variable will be available in them template you specified in mymodule_theme() (custom-theme-template.tpl.php)
  }
  if ($hook == 'page') {
    $vars['variable'] = 'string'; // $variable will be available in page.tpl.php
  }
  if ($hook == 'html') {
    $vars['variable'] = 'string'; // $variable will be available in html.tpl.php
  }
}
```