# Check if a module is enabled with JavaScript

Tags: 7, ajax

How do I check if a module is enabled using JavaScript? I want to avoid unnecessary Ajax calls that cause 403 errors since the module is not enabled.

```
if (mymodule_exist) {
  // Make an Ajax call.
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/player/status",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
      player_value = data;
    }
  });
}
```

I am trying to do something like this. How do I do it efficiently?

Comment: Are you sure it's the simplest way for fix your problem ?
Can you just not add the AJAX part in your module if the require module isn't enabled ?
Or can you just add the require module in the .info file of your module ? Hope that help.

Comment: @NicolasPERNOT : `Can you just not add the AJAX part in your module if the require module isn't enabled -`

I dont think we can  make ajax call in module, ajax call is made only in JS , AM i right?  ... what are you trying to say

Comment: I believe what Nicolas PERNOT is saying is: Construct a module to output the ajax call - have it check to see if the appropriate module exists, if it does it would output the code, if not, no output. This has the added benefit of not poluting the DOM with unnecessary markup and code.

Comment: @Geoff : Thanks !!! that does make sense ... but which one is better ?

Comment: The approach that NicolasPERNOT is suggesting would be best I suspect. Since it defers the workload onto the server from the clients computer - this should result in faster, smoother page loads without unusable markup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check module is enabled or not using [module_exists](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_exists/7) function... Ideally your .module which checks for above condition and sets variable for `JavaScript` file goes below..

See detailed steps below on adding this condition

- Create a folder called 'custom' in `sites/all/modules`
- Create a folder called 'mycustomjs' in above custom folder
- Create a file called 'mycustomjs.info' inside above folder with

below code

```
name = My Custom JS Alters
description = A custom module to interact with JS
core = 7.x
package = Custom
```

Create a file called mycustomjs.module inside 'mycustomjs' folder with
below code

```
<?php

function mycustomjs_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $module = "MODULENAME"; // Change modulename to module you want to verify
  $does_module_enabled = module_exists($module);
  if ($does_module_enabled) {
    drupal_add_js(array('MODULENAME' => array('enabled' => TRUE)), 'setting');
  }
  else {
    drupal_add_js(array('MODULENAME' => array('enabled' => FALSE)), 'setting');
  }  
}

?>
```

For more information See the [Creating Drupal 7.x modules](https://drupal.org/developing/modules/7) if you're not sure

Comment: great!!! I am liitle new to drupal so I have one question 
 `mycustomjs_preprocess_page` can be changed to any function name like 'my_function_setting_variable' or it has to follow the `my_module` name , ?

Comment: It always should by MODULENAME_preprocess_page ... So mycustomjs_preprocess_page .. see more about preprocess functions [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7)

Comment: Thanks my mistake was I was making custom function `function mysettings()` and was getting error `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` 

I changed it to `HOOK_PREPROCESSOR_PAGE` as you suggessted and also got some help from here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/76565/26318 and http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74708/what-is-the-difference-between-hook-preprocess-page-and-hook-preprocess-html....Thanks for help ... now I am going to try calling setting variable in JS side :)

Answer (score 10):

I can think of two ways:

- Send a JavaScript flag as settings, indicating the module is active:

  ```
  drupal_add_js(array('my_module' => array('enabled' => TRUE)), 'setting');
  ```
- If the module is enabled, modify the output in some way so the JavaScript code that makes the petition is included only when your module is enabled, or the contrary way, make sure that code is not included if your module is disabled: you will have to use another module or some kind of configuration. The exact way depends on the origin of the JavaScript code that makes the Ajax petitions.

Comment: I understood the first point and it makes sense, can you elaborate second point please. thanks

Comment: Even First point should be done within some module !!! Am I correct ? and if "mymodule" is not even installed in my certain server than I need to keep this   `drupal_add_js(array('my_module' => array('enabled' => TRUE)), 'setting');` in another common module my_common_module of my site ....... 

can you tell me in that case what will be the correct way for this 
1. `drupal_add_js(array('my_module' => array('enabled' => TRUE)), 'setting');`
or 
2.`drupal_add_js(array('my_common_module' => array('enabled' => TRUE)), 'setting');`

Comment: Well, it depends on the origin of code that makes the AJAX petition. The idea is to avoid this code to be sent to the client if your module is not enabled (you will need another module or some configuration) or add this code if your module is enabled. The eactly way of doing it depends on the irigin of that code. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: ;) Same question asked in next comment !!! Please edit your answer :) it will really be helpful , also if you can add some helpful links it would be great help ...Thanks

Comment: I can't give you more info with more details about the origin of that petitions.

Comment: hmmm :) np , you already gave lot of information thanks

Comment: Is there any common php file you can recommend, where I can keep this setting variable , I am not sure why but mytheme is breaking after I use this in `mymodule.module` file

Comment: In mymodule.module is fine, if your theme is broken is not because where you put the function call. You can create a new question with your code and theme errors.